How do I set the minimum SDK to 19 in Android Studio?
I'm required to make an application that is compatible with Android 4.4 devices, and I tried testing Android Studio if it'd be doable using the IDE. However, the minimum SDK that I can choose for a new project is 21 / Android 5.0. I tried installing the 4.4 SDK through the tab 'Languages & Frameworks' > 'Android SDK' but I still can't choose this SDK. I also tried creating a project with a minimum SDK of 21 and change minSdk to 19 in build.gradle.kts and got the error 'uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library'.
I'm not familiar with Android development, is it possible program 4.4-compatible applications in Android Studio only in older versions as Google stopped supporting 4.4?

In app/build.gradle do the following:
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whatever.app"
        minSdkVersion 19 //This one
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

